# Refine a variable that Assign src of image into a variable through JS combined with a variable of changing letters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, variables

I have a variable of changing letters that are changing at some specific intervals.
Now in this fast roulette, I would like to add also images that are appearing combined with those letters

e.g.

'letters'

'letters'

'letters'

'image.jpg',

'image.jpg',

'image.jpg',

'letters'

'letters'

**HERE THE SNIPPET IN ACTION:**

https://codepen.io/cat999/pen/bGBBVgm

The code part is extremely simple, please have a look:

```
var a = [, 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'De', 'De', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'D', 'd', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'De', 'De', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'D', 'd', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'De', 'De', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'D', 'd', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o',
    'image.jpg',
    'image.jpg',
    'image.jpg',
];

c = 0, 5;
setInterval(function() {
    c++;
    var letter = a[c];
    var length = a.length;
    if (c > length) { c = 0, 5; }
    $("body").text(letter);
}, 25);
```

**COULD YOU KINDLY HELP ME TO REFINE MY VARIABLE SO ALSO IMAGES ("image.jpg") COULD APPEAR IN THIS FAST ROULETTE?**

Looking forward to your precious help°

Comment: what do you want exactly? Do you want images to appear as well?

Comment: what about adding a check, if the last 4 characters is ```.jpg``` or ```.png``` then show an ```<img>``` element with it's src pointing to the image?

Comment: @ AD-1  Exactly!

Comment: @Kristian Could you teach me the way through my code or editing my codepen? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about adding a check, if the last 4 characters is `.jpg` or `.png` then show an `<img>` element with it's src pointing to the image?

click "run code snippet" (image taken from google's logo since it's small and fast to load)

```js
var a = [, 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'De', 'De', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'D', 'd', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'De', 'De', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'D', 'd', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'De', 'De', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'D', 'd', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o',
    'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
    'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
    'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
    'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
    'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
    'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
    'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
    'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
    'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
];

c = 0, 5;
setInterval(function() {
    c++;
    var letter = a[c];
    var length = a.length;
    if (c > length) { c = 0, 5; }
    
  if(letter != undefined && letter.length>5 && (letter.substr(letter.length-4, 4)==".png" || letter.substr(letter.length-4, 4)==".jpg") ) {
    $("#mydiv").html("<img src='"+letter+"'>");
  } else { 
    $("#mydiv").text(letter);
  }
}, 25);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```